# Why doesn't my comparison counting function count swaps?

Tags: java

So this code does count comparisions but is not counting swaps (countswap in each loop).

Does anyone know why, is it too "embedded or something? Thanks a million for any help.

```
 */
package sorts;

import java.util.*;

public class Sorts {

    Random rand = new Random();

    private int countcomp;
    private int countswap;

    public Sorts() {
        countcomp = 0;
        countswap = 0;
    }

    public int getcomparisions() {
        return countcomp;
    }

    public int getswaps() {
        return countswap;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Sorts sorts = new Sorts();

        //int[] unsorted = {2, 4, 1, 9, 5, 10, 3, 6, 8, 7};
        //int[] unsorted = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        //int[] unsorted = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int[] unsorted = new int[100];
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            unsorted[i] = i;
    }
        //GENERATOR OF INT ARRAYS

        System.out.println("\n\tSelection sort");
        Sorts sortsselect = new Sorts();
        sortsselect.selection(unsorted);
        System.out.println("\nSwap Count : " + sortsselect.getswaps() + "\nComparision Count : " + sortsselect.getcomparisions());

        System.out.println("\n\tBubble sort");
        Sorts sortsbubble = new Sorts();
        sortsbubble.bubble(unsorted);
        System.out.println("\nSwap Count : " + sortsbubble.getswaps() + "\nComparision Count : " + sortsbubble.getcomparisions());

        System.out.println("\n\n\tInsertion sort");
        Sorts sortsinsertion = new Sorts();
        sortsinsertion.insertion(unsorted);
        System.out.println("\nSwap Count : " + sortsinsertion.getswaps() + "\nComparision Count : " + sortsinsertion.getcomparisions());

        System.out.println("\n\n\tExchange sort");
        Sorts sortsexchange = new Sorts();
        sortsexchange.exchange(unsorted);
        System.out.println("\nSwap Count : " + sortsexchange.getswaps() + "\nComparision Count : " + sortsexchange.getcomparisions());

    }

    //selection takes in a unsorted array and returns a sorted one
    public void selection(int[] selunsorted) {

        int i, j, max;
        countcomp = 0;
        countswap = 0;
        max = selunsorted.length;

        //iterate through the array and move the smallest number into an incrementing position
        for (i = 0; i < max - 1; i++) {
            int smallpos = i;
            int smallest = selunsorted[i];

            for (j = i + 1; j < max; j++) {
                countcomp++;
                if (selunsorted[j] < smallest) {
                    countswap++;
                    smallest = selunsorted[j];
                    smallpos = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = selunsorted[i];
            selunsorted[i] = selunsorted[smallpos];
            selunsorted[smallpos] = temp;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            j = selunsorted[i];
            System.out.print(j + ",");
        }
    }

    public void bubble(int[] bubunsorted) {

        int max = bubunsorted.length;
        int i, imax, j;
        countcomp = 0;
        countswap = 0;

        for (imax = max; imax > 0; imax--) {
            for (j = 0; j + 1 < imax; j++) {
                countcomp++;
                if (bubunsorted[j] > bubunsorted[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = bubunsorted[j + 1];
                    bubunsorted[j + 1] = bubunsorted[j];
                    bubunsorted[j] = temp;
                    countswap++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            j = bubunsorted[i];
            System.out.print(j + ",");
        }
    }

    public void insertion(int[] insertunsorted) {

        int i, j, a;
        int max = insertunsorted.length;
        countcomp = 0;
        countswap = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                countcomp++;
            }
            if (insertunsorted[j] > insertunsorted[i]) {
                int temp = insertunsorted[j + 1];
                insertunsorted[j + 1] = insertunsorted[i];
                countswap++;
                for (a = (j + 2); a < (i + 1); a++) {
                    int temp1 = insertunsorted[a];
                    insertunsorted[a] = temp;
                    temp = temp1;
                    countswap++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            j = insertunsorted[i];
            System.out.print(j + ",");
        }
    }

    public void exchange(int[] exchangeunsorted) {

        int max = exchangeunsorted.length;
        int i, j;
        countcomp = 0;
        countswap = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            for (j = i; j < max; j++) {
                countcomp++;
                if (exchangeunsorted[j] < exchangeunsorted[i]) {
                    countswap++;
                    int temp = exchangeunsorted[j];
                    exchangeunsorted[i] = exchangeunsorted[j];
                    exchangeunsorted[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            j = exchangeunsorted[i];
            System.out.print(j + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `System.out.println` they are very useful in determining the program flow and check where it is getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

See your **array initialization** at the starting of **your main()** method: -

```
int[] unsorted = new int[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        unsorted[i] = i;
}
```

Your array is already sorted.. So, no swaps will take place.. So, swapCount is 0.. But still comparison will be done.. hence they are counted..

Try with smaller size array.. And add random value to it.. which are not sorted.. It will work..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are creating a sorted array, so no swaps are happening.
You should do something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)  {
unsorted[i] = r.nextInt(500);
}
```

You also need to make a new unsorted array for each different sorting algorithm (or just copy the array using Arrays.copyOf(array)), as the array will be sorted by the first sorting algorithm. Swaps displays correctly if you do that.

Also I copied and tested your code, and there is something wrong somewhere in exchange sort or insertion sort, as the output on exchange sort was a lot of 1's.